# FFMPEG Merging Sources

Tags: ffmpeg, concatenation

I am having some trouble with creating a .MKV out file correctly.

The goal here is to be able to support a video input and two separate audio sources (in this case they are mono channeled audio mics) - the goal is to combine the audio recording sources and the video source into a single .MKV file with a 2 channel stereo created from the two mono devices muxed together.

The code I have so far is below:

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -video_size 1280x720 -framerate 30 -rtbufsize 700200k -i video="Logitech HD Pro Webcam C920" -r 30000/1001 -f dshow -channels 1 -i audio="Microphone (USB PnP Audio Device)" -f dshow -channels 1 -i audio="Microphone (3- USB PnP Audio Device)" -b:a 192k -ar 48000 -filter_complex "[0:1][1:0][2:0]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[v][a]" -map "[v]" -flags +global_header -profile:v main -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v libx264 -map "[a]" -c:a aac -ar 48000 -ac 2 -f tee "test.mkv | test2.mkv | [f=mpegts]udp://localhost:4000" -filter_complex "[0:a]astats=metadata=1:reset=1,ametadata@VUone=print:key=lavfi.astats.1.RMS_level[0a];[1:a]astats=metadata=1:reset=1,ametadata@VUTwo=print:key=lavfi.astats.1.RMS_level[1a];[0a][1a]amerge=inputs=2[aout]" -map "[aout]" -acodec flac -f tee "test.flac | test2.flac"
```

I'm getting the following error however...

> Input #0, dshow, from 'video=Logitech HD Pro Webcam C920':
>     Duration: N/A, start: 15120.108000, bitrate: N/A
>       Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo, bgr24, 1280x720, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 10000k tbn, 10000k tbc
>   Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #1.0 : mono
>   Input #1, dshow, from 'audio=Microphone (USB PnP Audio Device)':
>     Duration: N/A, start: 15120.307000, bitrate: 705 kb/s
>       Stream #1:0: Audio: pcm_s16le, 44100 Hz, mono, s16, 705 kb/s
>   Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #2.0 : mono
>   Input #2, dshow, from 'audio=Microphone (3- USB PnP Audio Device)':
>     Duration: N/A, start: 15120.976000, bitrate: 705 kb/s
>       Stream #2:0: Audio: pcm_s16le, 44100 Hz, mono, s16, 705 kb/s
>   Stream specifier ':0' in filtergraph description [0:0][1:0][2:0]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[v][a] matches no streams.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong because it looks logically, at least to me, like that should work.  The first stream from the first input would be the video stream yes?

Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: What's the reason for using the concat filter?

Comment: There really isn't one specifically - I was originally trying to use the "amerge" filter but I couldn't get that to work either and this is where I left off.  If you have another suggestion I'm all ears.  Ultimately all I'm trying to do is set this up where I can create a .MKV file with video and stereo channels from two mono devices (for example, one mic on one side of the room and one mic on another) and then mix those two audio inputs into a stereo audio for the audio portion of the MKV file.  I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

The [join](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#join) or [amerge](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amerge) filters will allow you to mix two mono inputs to a stereo output. Simplified examples:

#### join

```
ffmpeg -i video -i mic1 -i mic2 -filter_complex "[1][2]join=inputs=2:channel_layout=stereo[a]" -map 0:v -map "[a]" output
```

#### amerge

```
ffmpeg -i video -i mic1 -i mic2 -filter_complex "[1][2]amerge=inputs=2[a]" -map 0:v -map "[a]" -ac 2 output
```

Comment: Using the "amerge" command this does seem to work - however, I get a video delay when utilizing this.  The audio is about 1-2 seconds faster than the video.  Mapping out each source individually, however, does not result in a delay.  Also, do you have any insight into why one microphone does not seem to actually be recording anything when utilizing two input microphones?  Each on their own works perfectly fine, however.  If I talk into one for example its really loud but talking into the other seems quiet as if its really just the first mic picking up my voice from far away despite showing up

Comment: @R.Mizell Hard to say without seeing your command and complete log. You can use a pastebin site and provide the link here in a comment.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/5gL0w154             -- There's a bunch of  lines that are just reporting the dB values for each microphone but that's not super important.  My biggest issue is that there is a very clear and distinct maybe 1 second delay where the audio is slightly ahead of the video.  Luckily it appears that since restarting my computer the file does appear to be capturing both microphones correct and mixing correct - I just need to fix the delay.  I appreciate your help.

Comment: @R.Mizell Does it delay only after you use amerge? In other words, if you don't filter, is there a delay? You should only be using one `-filter_complex`: all filtering can be done in one filtergraph. dshow uses the `-sample_rate` input option, so use that instead of `-ar` output option to avoid potentially needless re-sampling. Simplify your command. Once you get it to work then use tee.

Comment: No - if I map it individually there is no delay.  The problem with that though is that I end up with separate tracks for each MKV file.   One of the requirements for my project is that I need to be able to save the MKV file with all of it's requirements to two different file locations and also stream it to a local port that VLC can pick up and display (as like a real time preview etc.)  - but I also need to set up the audio only portion to two different file locations in the FLAC format.  Part of this means that with the FLAC i want to utilize all channels but with MKV mix down all channels

Comment: @R.Mizell Simplify your command until you find the culprit and then we can go from there.